# getting all trimester between time periods

Tags: javascript

Here  are my trimesters:

```
Jan to Apr = Trimester #1

May to Aug= Trimester #2

Sep to Dec = Trimester #3
```

With this in mind, we have two date pickers where we choose our dates from.

These dates are then placed in their relevant trimesters and an API query is made in which the API request parameters are the year from the date picker and trimesters from the two dates.

Example:

```
localhost:5000/subscription?year=2019&trimester=1&choice=1
```

The choice can only be 1 or 2 so we can hard code this.

We make a bar graph plot from the response of the API.

So we make two requests like the one above but with the choice being 2. The program works fine when the year is the same.

I need help on how to make it work when the years are different.

Example:

```
localhost:5000/subscription?year=2019&trimester=1&choice=1
localhost:5000/subscription?year=2021&trimester=1&choice=2
```

So i need a way to handle this. Please help

Comment: How exactly does it not work when the year is different? Does the API not return the right thing, or do you need help putting two years on one bar chart?